# Error "file_get_contents" if link content utf-8 character

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I get

> Warning: `file_get_contents(http://images.hotdeals.vn/images/03-01-2014/Bộ 2 Loa X&iacute; Ngầu/51693_0_body_01.jpg)`: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
>   HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in C:\xampp\htdocs\tasklist\controller\admin\addProduct.php on line 60

when I try download image with URL `http://images.hotdeals.vn/images/03-01-2014/Bộ 2 Loa Xí Ngầu/51693_0_body_01.jpg`.
Any help. Thanks.

Comment: Replace the spaces with `%20`

Comment: `urlencode` the filename

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that directory name. This works for me...

```
file_get_contents('http://images.hotdeals.vn/images/03-01-2014/'
        . rawurlencode('Bộ 2 Loa Xí Ngầu') . '/51693_0_body_01.jpg')
```

If you need something more dynamic, try this...

```
$url = 'http://images.hotdeals.vn/images/03-01-2014/Bộ 2 Loa Xí Ngầu/51693_0_body_01.jpg';

$info = parse_url($url);
$safePath = implode('/', array_map('rawurlencode', explode('/', $info['path'])));

$newUrl = sprintf('%s://%s%s', $info['scheme'], $info['host'], $safePath);

// http://images.hotdeals.vn/images/03-01-2014/B%E1%BB%99%202%20Loa%20X%C3%AD%20Ng%E1%BA%A7u/51693_0_body_01.jpg
```

Demo here - http://ideone.com/Abr1OO